# Why are my div's not appearing at all? - NO CSS/JS

Tags: html

I have an issue where 2/4 div's are not appearing at all in the markup when the page loads in the browser. There isn't any script/CSS involved here at all.

I have tried to isolate my markup by creating a fiddle and then trying but still can't figure out what's wrong. I have run the markup through a HTML lint as well just to be sure.

Here's my markup

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Subnet</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <select class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Type</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <select class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Team</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <select class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Machine Type</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <select class="form-control"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the fiddle is at - https://jsfiddle.net/zpsygxsq/4/

Can someone take a look and advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Apporopriate tag and complete that.... Select tag is not autocomplete tag.. it must be closed in html... So use

```
<select class="form-control"></select>
```

Instead Of

```
<select class="form-control" />
```

**Checkout Your Following Snippest With Correction**

```html
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Subnet</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <select class="form-control"></select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Type</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <select class="form-control"></select>      
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Team</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <select class="form-control"></select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Machine Type</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <select class="form-control"></select>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its becasue your self closing the select tags.

proper markup is.

```
<select class="form-control"></select>
```

not

```
 <select class="form-control" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no content /text in your structure that may be the reason.